# How to swipe left using ruby cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, appium, swipe

I have to swipe x number of times to view the main page.
If I use
delta = {:x => 0.0, :y => 0.0} 
flick("com.test.app:id/textView_slideshow", delta)

I get an error
Cannot swipe in {:x=>0.0, :y=>0.0} (RuntimeError)

The swipe and pan functions do not work in ruby

Comment: Hi, @dexter, I think we need way more context to help you.

Comment: Maybe you should use swipe? http://www.rubydoc.info/github/appium/ruby_lib/Appium/TouchAction:swipe

Comment: Thanks keith and Sander
instead of flick I used

Appium::TouchAction.new.swipe(start_x: 0.90 , start_y: 0.5, offset_x: 0.5, offset_y: 0.5, duration:500).perform

with the above line i could swipe left


here's the link to the site 

https://discuss.appium.io/t/left-to-right-swipe-doesnt-work-for-me-android-appium-using-ruby-cucumber/19950/2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks keith and Sander
instead of flick I used

Appium::TouchAction.new.swipe(start_x: 0.90 , start_y: 0.5, offset_x: 0.5, offset_y: 0.5, duration:500).perform

with the above line i could swipe left

here's the link to the site

https://discuss.appium.io/t/left-to-right-swipe-doesnt-work-for-me-android-appium-using-ruby-cucumber/19950/2